# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List<org.springframework.shell.ParameterResolver>'

Tags: java, spring, scala, shell, spring-boot

I'm currently trying to create a Spring Shell Application in Scala.
It works in IntelliJ but does not work when creating the jar.

I have a working proof of concept in Java, that does also successfully create a running jar.

However, my Scala version fails with several:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'parameterValidationExceptionResultHandler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'parameterResolvers'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List<org.springframework.shell.ParameterResolver>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I've tried several minimal examples, moving the classes around (same package) and different Spring annotations (like @SpringBootApplication for both).

Java version:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@ShellComponent
public class MyCommands {

    @ShellMethod("Add two integers together.")
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Scala Version:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
class DemoApplication

object Scark extends App {
  SpringApplication.run(classOf[DemoApplication], args:_*)
}

@ShellComponent class MyCommands {
  @ShellMethod("Add two integers together.") def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
}
```

I expect to also be able to successfully build a jar from the Scala version.

Edit: I've uploaded the minimal example:
https://github.com/Zethson/Scala-Spring-Shell-Example/tree/feature/minimal_scala_issues_SO

Answer (score 0):

1. It does not matter at which path you have placed your component(Bean) if you are using component scan first it will check it in current package and then to its sub packages. If your component is placed at different path then include the path in **@ComponentScan("Path")**
2. Also make sure to check after applying DEBUG mode in **application.properties** in java for Spring Boot whether your component is being scanned or not , if not try using **@Component** just above the component wherever it is , since **@SpringBootApplication** scans the same while startup.

If I answered incorrectly , do let me know your response and elaborate further. 
Happy Coding :)

Comment: There's already a ShellComponent annotation for the MyCommands class. It is successfully scanned (from what I can see).

I've uploaded my minimal working issue to Github: 
https://github.com/Zethson/Scala-Spring-Shell-Example/tree/feature/minimal_scala_issues_SO

Maybe, if you have time, you could take a quick look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be unable to resolve your shell command parameters. Can you try this :

```
@ShellComponent class MyCommands {
  @ShellMethod("Add two integers together.") def add(
    @ShellOption(mandatory = true) a: Int, 
    @ShellOption(mandatory = true) b: Int): Int = a + b
}
```

Comment: According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/current/api/org/springframework/shell/standard/ShellOption.html there is no mandatory option.

I added  the ShellOptions without any success. Error persists.

I've uploaded the minimal example to here: 
https://github.com/Zethson/Scala-Spring-Shell-Example/tree/feature/minimal_scala_issues_SO

Would be highly appreciated if you could take a look. Thanks.

Comment: I managed to make it work in Java, still trying in Scala but it is not straightforward

Comment: Did you come up with a solution? I am still lost.

Comment: I couldn't get your minimal version to work.

I made this Scala version work :
```@SpringBootApplication
class DemoShellApplication

object DemoApplication {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = SpringApplication.run(classOf[DemoShellApplication], args :_ *)
}

@ShellComponent class MyCommands {
  @ShellMethod("Add two integers together.") def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
}```

using SBT instead of Maven.

Note that I used Spring Boot 2.0 and Spring Shell 2.0

Comment: Also if you consider upgrading from Spring Shell 1.2 to 2.0 this may be of help https://devops.datenkollektiv.de/migrating-from-spring-shell-12-to-20.html

Comment: I am using Spring shell 2.0 on this branch. 

Would you mind sharing your full sbt project setup?
I would like to test the jar creation.

Comment: I'll push that on my github, keep you posted

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately the generated jar on your repository doesn't work either for me. I opened an issue on your repository.